# Scanning files for player data

Tags: java, string, file, libgdx

I'm trying to scan a file I have for player data and set the player data equal to what's in the file. The file would look like I want to save data to it and read player data. How would I?

```
HP = 10
Atk = 2
Def = 5;
```

and I need to set this to the players' health and such. Here is what I use.

```
 File dir = new File("c:\\Project0\\data\\Playerstuff");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (dir.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            }

String fileName="hi";
        File tagFile=new File(dir,fileName+".txt");
        if(!tagFile.exists()){
        try {



            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tagFile.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("HP: " + p.getAtk());
            bw.close();

            Scanner s = new Scanner(tagFile);
            s.findInLine("HP: ");
        } catch (IOException ie) {ie.printStackTrace(); System.out.println("Error loading game directory");}
        }
```

Comment: OK. What seems to be a problem?  What stops you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would be reading and writing at the same time, and the spacing of how you are saving the data doesn't seem to lend itself well to being read from. I'd try saving the data as, for example

```
HP=10
ATK=2
DEF=5
```

And then when you're reading the data:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(tagFile);
while(s.hasNextLine()) {
    String info = s.nextLine();
    if (info.startsWith("HP") {
        int hp = Integer.parseInt(info.substring(info.indexOf("=" + 1),info.length()));
        p.setHP(hp);
    }
    else if (...) //Etc... for all the other values
}
```

The other way to do it, without the if/else, is to always keep the data in a certain order (e.g. hp first, then atk, then def), in which case you don't have to check. But that will probably end up being confusing.